# PHP : How to optimize the multiple conditional

Tags: php

I have a loop with multiple conditionals

```
foreach ($fields as $field_key => $value) {

if ($field_key !== 'a' && $field_key !== 'b' && $field_key !== '10200' && $field_key !== 'z' && $field_key !== 'y') {
 ...
//display $value;

}

}
```

*How to optimize the code to avoid the multiple conditionals in the if clause?*

I am thinking of filing an array with `{a, b, y, z}` an search against it for a value to not be found there, using **e.g** `in_array`, `search_array`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP native `in_array()` function:

```
$vals = array('a', 'b');

foreach ($fields as $field_key => $value) {

    if (!in_array($field_key, $vals)) {
         ...
        //display $value;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `in_array`:

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', '10200', 'z', 'y');

foreach ($fields as $field_key => $value) {
  if ( !in_array($field_key, $keys) ) {
    //display $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('a', 'b', '10200', 'z', 'y');

foreach ($fields as $field_key => $value) {    
    if (!in_array($field_key, $array)) {
    ...
    //display $value;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing `array` in first line.

Answer (score 0):

A different option.

```
ignore = array('a', 'b', '10200', 'z', 'y');
$allowed = array_diff_key($fields, array_combine($ignore, $ignore));
foreach ($allowed as $field_key => $field_value) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a lookup table:

```
$exclude = array('a' => true, 'b' => true , '10200' => true , 'z' => true, 'y' => true);

foreach ($fields as $field_key => $value) {
    if (!isset($exclude[$field_key])) {
        //display $value;
    }
}
```

Or filter the elements out beforehand:

```
$filtered_fields = array_diff_keys($fields, $exclude);

foreach($filtered_fields as $field_key => $value) {
    //display $value;
}
```

Comment: Not as efficient as using `in_array`. PHP wasting time for flipping your array.

Comment: @ArtemL: Then lets not use `array_flip`.

Comment: Sorry for wrong formatting... Your code is a bit slower with low number of items. bumz@artem-lubuntu-pc:/tmp/proof$ time php test1.php 

real 0m0.019s
user 0m0.012s
sys 0m0.004s
bumz@artem-lubuntu-pc:/tmp/proof$ time php test2.php 

real 0m0.024s
user 0m0.016s
sys 0m0.004s

Comment: yeah. Without array_flip it will be faster. But code will be like a bloatware.

Comment: @ArtemL: You always have to make compromises.